# MVC Url helper method for static pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

If I have a url like `"/something/something/"` and my site is `http://mysite.com` and I want to link to that something url, is there a method like `Url.Content();` which will discover the virtual directory of the site in IIS and map appropriately to a url path?

I tried `Url.GenerateContentUrl(), Url.Action(), Url.Content(), Url.RouteUrl()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there a method like Url.Content();

Why *like* when there is `Url.Content`?

```
var url = Url.Content("~/something/something");
```

which will take care of the virtual directory name and if your side is deployed at the root `http://example.com` it will return `/something/something` and if you have a virtual directory `http://example.com/applicationname` it will return `/applicationname/something/something`.

So everytime you need to link a static resource you should always use `Url.Content`. For example:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/images/foo.png") %>" alt="" />
```

will always correctly resolve the image url no matter where your site is deployed to.

Answer (score 1):

If, for whatever reason, you can't just use Url.Content, you can use either [HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationvirtualpath.aspx) or [HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) instead.

But I can't think of a good reason you can't just use Url.Content.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I assume:

You have a file like `myfile.jpg` on the root on your site. Then you want a url like:

```
http://mysite.com/myfile.jpg
```

Right?

All you need to do is add this in yours routes in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("myfile.jpg");
```

Yes it should work on sub folders too.

Comment: No, its a route that links to an action result, so there is no file extension, just a virutal route url. It literally looks like this: "/pagename/actionname/" but there is no controller or action method associated with it, since its just an entry in the routing table.

Comment: @Shawn I'm totally unclear about what you want? You want to expose files? Pages? What?

Comment: OK then what do you want when the user visits the url?

Comment: Server 1 is mapped to ROOT level of IIS (Mysite.com/PageName/RouteValue) Server 2 is in a Virutal Directory (MySite.com/VirtualDir/PageName/RouteValue) so if I hard code <a href="/pagename/routevalue"> it will break on Server 2, and vis versa on server 1.